# Login the user with phone number

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a Messaging App. In my App one can register with one's phone number. Everything works perfectly good. All this I do with Firebase.
[Here is the official documentation, where I learned it.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

1. But now I have a problem. Every time the Activity starts, it should automatically login, right? How can I do this?
2. And a little bit different Question. When the User logs out with: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`, how can he login? Because he only created a Account with phonenumber, without a password or anything....Only the sent sms code by firebase.

---

**EDIT:**

So I tried this:

```
if(mFirebaseUser != null) mFirebaseUser.reload().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
                    String exc = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Log.d("FireBaseUser", exc);
                    mFirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(ChatListActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    Log.d("FireBaseUser", "User doesnt exist");
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("FireBaseUser", "User is ok!");
                    return;
                }

            }
            else{
                Log.d("FireBaseUser", "????");
            }
        }
    });

    else {
        Log.d("FireBaseUser", "User is null");
    } }
    });
```

But it won't work. And the User can login... What I did wrong? And it seems that the code won't be run. Because I see nothing in my log. Everytime I run the code it puts out: User is null

Comment: Consider editing this question to ask only one of your questions at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (mUser == null) {
    // not logged-in
    // show login activity
} else {
    // logged-in
    String phoneNumber = mUser.getPhoneNumber();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So I already tried this. But there I have a Problem. When I delete or deactivate the User Account in my firebase pannel , user can login even when he havnt an account.

Comment: Try `mUser.reload()` function. You can also add `successListener` on `reload()`

Comment: Can you please look at my Edit in my Question

Comment: Inside `task.isSuccessfull()` check if `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null`. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you should save the phonenumber in SharedPreferences if first authentication was successful