# How can check if user exist in Login method in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, logic

In case , this is my Code in android to check if the user exists when login register but not the cod do, I check if userid but not a success and I don’t Know why, I want to help me why this problem

```
 mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
         mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

         login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login_Butt);
         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String Email_Field= email.getText().toString().trim();
                 String Pass_Field=Password.getText().toString().trim();

                 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Email_Field)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(Pass_Field)){

                                             mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( Email_Field,Pass_Field).
                             addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this ,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                             if (task.isSuccessful()){
                               CheckUserExists();
                                 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcommm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             }  
                         } });}
             }});}

    public void CheckUserExists(){

        final String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){
                    Intent LoginIntent= new Intent(LoginActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(LoginIntent);



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, " check your Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46979838/2166337

Comment: what is not working? is it entering `checkuserexists()` method?

Comment: I discovered the problem is Not in this function but for the first time, not login success but when close the app then open the Login in Success!